# How to resize the panel?

Tags: java

So I'm making a group project which is Java console GUI. This is my code for the Java console GUI:

```
package com.nono.groupproject;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class AdminRegistrationGUIConsole extends JFrame {

    private JTextField nameField, emailField, phoneNumberField;

    public AdminRegistrationGUIConsole() {
        setTitle("Admin Registration");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

       JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10, 10, 10));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        
        panel.add(new JLabel("Name:"));
        nameField = new JTextField();
        panel.add(nameField);
        nameField.setColumns(25);

        panel.add(new JLabel("Phone Number:"));
        phoneNumberField = new JTextField();
        panel.add(phoneNumberField);

        panel.add(new JLabel("Email:"));
        emailField = new JTextField();
        panel.add(emailField);
        
        JButton registerButton = new JButton("Register");
        registerButton.addActionListener(e -> handleRegistration(e));
        panel.add(registerButton);
        
        setContentPane(panel);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
}

    private void handleRegistration(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Registration Completed!");
        this.dispose();
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AdminRegistrationGUIConsole();
}
}
```

I want to resize the panel cause the bottom is to long. Here's the output from my code. Can somebody help me? Thanks...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6Gd8.png)

Comment: Change `panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10, 10, 10));` to `panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 10, 10, 10));` - I'd also recommend making the time to learn how to use [`GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can modify the GridLayout settings and set preferred sizes for components

```
package com.nono.groupproject;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class AdminRegistrationGUIConsole extends JFrame {

    private JTextField nameField, emailField, phoneNumberField;

    public AdminRegistrationGUIConsole() {
        setTitle("Admin Registration");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2, 10, 10)); // Adjusted rows and columns

        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        panel.add(new JLabel("Name:"));
        nameField = new JTextField();
        panel.add(nameField);
        nameField.setColumns(25);

        panel.add(new JLabel("Phone Number:"));
        phoneNumberField = new JTextField();
        panel.add(phoneNumberField);

        panel.add(new JLabel("Email:"));
        emailField = new JTextField();
        panel.add(emailField);

        JButton registerButton = new JButton("Register");
        registerButton.addActionListener(e -> handleRegistration(e));
        panel.add(registerButton);

        setContentPane(panel);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void handleRegistration(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Registration Completed!");
        this.dispose();
        // You might want to perform the actual registration logic here
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AdminRegistrationGUIConsole();
    }
}
```